# Is there a connection between partial reflection and formation of virtual image?

Tags: optics, reflection, geometric-optics

If light rays do not intersect, there won't be any photons, but if we can see a virtual image there should be a source. Is there then a partial reflection connected to this?

Comment: actually if we backtrace a path our eyes can only see rectilinearly. So a reflected ray appears to look as if it is coming from a source inside the mirror that is virtual(does not exist)

Comment: To my knowledge partial reflection is because of sime light absorbed by the surface and you cannot relate it to this

Comment: You said, "If light rays don't meet actually there won't be photons." Can you say that differently? What do you mean? Light _is_ photons. Photons _are_ light. In what sense are you talking about "light rays" with no photons?

Comment: I meant 'no light rays' and obviously no photons as well

Answer (score 0):

The location of a virtual image does not depend on the fraction of light reflected.  My image in my computer screen does not change shape when I look at dark or light areas of the screen.